# Hive create table for json data

Tags: hive

I am trying to create the hive table which can read the json data, but when I am executing the create statement it is throwing an error.

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_exp_json
( id INT,
fname STRING,
lname STRING,
profession STRING,
experience INT,
exp_service STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serede2.Jsonserede'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serede2.Jsonserede

I have also added the jar `hive-json-serde.jar`, but I'm still facing the same issue. I am creating this table on cloudera and hive version is 1.1.0.

Comment: 1) You have a typo in **serede2** 2) JSONSerde is not in that package https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2

Answer (score 0):

The correct class name is

```
org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
```

Refer: [Hive SerDes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe)

As for the other JAR you added, [check its documentation](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde/blob/develop/README.md). Still a different class

```
org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the json-serde-with-dependencies.jar.
You can Download it from  [Download Hive Serde](http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3/cdh5/) 
Also try the class 
 
'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'